# Similarity between two samples of spacialized data ignoring local fluctuations

Tags: spatial, similarities

I have data from a set of sensors, and would like to measure similarity between two samples of data ignoring local fluctuations.

My problem is, my sensors are not regularly placed : some are quite alone, others are many in the same area, there is no regular pattern in their locations.

I want to measure similarity in terms of large scale, local fluctuations (even of high amplitude) are much less important as long as they are balanced by other nearby fluctuations.

I though about computing average values of a point and its neighbours, and making my indicator as the sum of absolute value of differences between the local averages of my two samples, but I have not idea whether it's a good approach or not.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a panel dataset, correct? (Has both cross-sectional and time series data)

Comment: Yes, indeed. And avoiding local balanced temporal fluctuations may be relevant as well, now that you mention it...

Comment: So essentially, do you want to pick out a large fluctuation that affects many sensors?

Comment: A large fluctuation affecting many close sensors is indeed important, but a fluctuation affecting a lonely sensor is important as well (as I can't tell how local it is).

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is probably both spatially and temporally correlated, you may want to look into a differences-in-differences model. This provides controls for both time (maybe some event occurs that affects every sensor) and space (maybe one sensor is located in an area that inherently gets more hits). Hope that this model works for your problem!